# Use routerlink or href based on condition

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router

I have this piece of code in a component

```
<a *ngFor="let item of config.socialLinks" [routerLink]="[item.url]">
...
</a>
```

This works as expected when is using local routes that are defined in the app.component but when external routes it redirects to http:localhost:5555 | http://external.com
Is there a way to use routerLink for local routes and href for external routes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is because, the directive `[routerLink]` is only for internal route system, and external links should be declarated in the `href` like this:

```
<a *ngFor="let item of config.socialLinks" href="{{item.url}}"></a>
```

Enjoy.

Comment: No need to add the comment about your bad English everywhere. It's definitely good enough.